# Windows Hosting Advice about Sending Bulk Emails

Tags: email, asp-classic, hosting

I run an ecard site.

When someone is sent an ecard, they get an email to say they have an ecard to read.

When it has been read, if the "read receipt" flag was ticked when the ecard was sent, the recipient will also get an email to say the ecard has been read.

Generally approximately 100 ecards a day are sent from the site.

That means about 200 emails a day are sent.

The site is busiest at Valentines, when approx 4 to 5,000 ecards can be sent.

Over Xmas (e.g. December 2013) about 38k ecards were sent, with about 10 days in a row where more than 1,000 ecards were sent each day (peaking about about 4 or 5 thousand).

My host has recently contacted me to say that have a send limit on their SMTP server of 1000 emails a day.

Hotmail blacklisted their SMTP server because my site sent about 1,300 emails a day to hotmail on 25th and 26th December 2013, and Hotmail said my notification emails were spam.

I am thinking of moving host, but one other host I contacted also have a 1,000 a day limit.

I wondered if anyone knows of a windows hosting package which offers more than that (e.g. up to 5 or 10,000 a day (though I would only hit that limit once or twice a year).

I can't afford a dedicated server.

My only other option is to either get rid of read receipts, and / or restrict the number of ecards sent from the site each day, which seems a bit restrictive but as my host are threatening account termination or legal action if I exceed the limit again I need to start looking at alternatives.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using an api with a specialist mailing company? http://mandrill.com/  is Mailchimp's version.  There would be some cost associated, but I don't think it would be much with the quantity you're sending and certainly much less than a dedicated server

Comment: Thank you Martin - that looks very interesting. I'll definitely investigate that. Wow - brilliant. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @20130215 Maybe of interest, read about why the classified you as spam. Not only the amount of emails are due to that classification. Google has some nice article about the subject I read once (damn can't find it), this one also handles some of those details: http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/smtp-configuration-and-e-mail-deliverability/ look for SPF records and PTR records in google.

Comment: @20130215 Probably you have an email connection at home [or at work for that matter]. With any ISP, and fair change they have a SMTP server which you can address from you own private mailbox. That SMTP server allowes you to send emails. Fair change you can use that SMTP server directly from you own ASP pages. It will be a bit slower, but hey... fast enough. But... Your ISP wants to make sure that only one of their customers are using that SMTP server. They have several ways for that, one is username and password. Use that SMTP, username and password from within your ASP page.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to restrict the max amount sent each day, set the max to 998.

but here is some list i pull ed that you may find helpful

http://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/lists-of-hosts-and-their-sending-limits/

IPowerWeb seems to be the best choice

have you also tried using more then 1 list ? most have a restriction on the mailing list saying 1000 emails "per mailing list"

create several accounts that will send out the list divided per day

this may also be helpful

http://group-mail.com/sending-email/email-sending-limits-for-isp-web-hosting-and-free-email-providers/

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) Move to a VPS host. Not sure what your budget is but there are fairly cheap plans for Windows VPS hosting (I have seen plans for US$15 per month). You will have your own IP address and SMTP server, so your host should not complain.

2) Use an external SMTP server. I found [one such service](http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/misc/616013-innovative-unique-rent-your-own-smtp-mail-server-send-unlimited-emails-free-vps.html)
 for US$30 per month that allows you to send unlimited emails of any type you want.

Other advice is to ensure that you have done as much as possible to avoid being flagged as spam such as setup SPF record and DKIM, and also read up on how to create emails that are less likely to be treated as spam.